# how can I ask my telegram bot user to share his contacts with bot?

Tags: bots, telegram

how can I ask my telegram  bot user to share his contacts with bot ?
any inline keys or commands?

I want the output to be contacts chat id

Answer (score 1):

```
$keyboard = json_encode([
'resize_keyboard'=>true,
'keyboard'=>[
[['text'=>"request contact",'request_contact'=>true]]
]
]);
```

Comment: thanks Destroyer but I want my user to share his friends contact, not himself. I want to show the list of contacts to choose when pressing a key

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to get contact of bot user (not user`s contact) with KeyboardButton (request_contact=True)

(is used it in python-telegram-bot v13.13 library)

you can read more in
[telegram core bots KeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton)